# Create a python script and use grep command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm creating a script wherein I want to grep all a specific address based on the list?

before what I usually do run a grep 1 by 1 using this command ex. **grep "192.168.1.1" ***

Now I'm creating a script.

Example of the output.

```
print(i) output.
192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

but how to call the list and put into loop under os.system so I can grep all the list?

Thanks

```
import ipaddress
import os

#Ask the ipaddress in CIDR format
ip = input("Enter the IP/CIDR: ")

os.chdir("/rs/configs")
print("pwd=%s" % os.getcwd())

for i in ipaddress.IPv4Network(ip):
    print (i)
    os.system("grep $i '*') #<--Grep from list and run to all directory *
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is `"grep {} '*'".format(ip)` but there are a number of problems with your script.

To improve usability, I would suggest you change the script so it accepts a list of IP addresses as command-line arguments instead.

You want to avoid `os.system()` in favor of `subprocess.run()`

There is no need to `cd` to the directory which contains the files you want to examine.

Finally, there is no need really to run `grep`, as Python itself is quite capable of searching a set of files.

```
import ipaddress
import glob

ips = set([ipaddress.IPv4Network(ip) for ip in sys.argv[1:]])

for file in glob.glob('/rs/configs/*'): 
    with open(file) as lines:
        for line in lines:
            if any(x in line for x in ips):
                print("{0}:{1}".format(file, line))
```

This should be significantly more efficient by way of examining the files only once.

It's not entirely clear what you hope to gain by using `ipaddress` here if you are grepping for individual IP addresses anyway.

Comment: Thanks, But I have tried using this code and its now working.                                                         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vr3.py", line 12, in <module>
    for line in lines:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 7094: invalid start byte

Comment: If your files use some random encoding, you need to specify it separately. The sane way forward is to use UTF-8 for all your textual data. Or are these not text files?

Comment: As a quick and dirty workaround, try `open(file, encoding='cp1252')`but understand that blindly assuming a random encoding is really a bug. For what it's worth, I don't think `grep` will work reliably in this scenario, either.